# How does "off" fit in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions

I was just studying the various meanings of 'off' on http://english.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/off and I stuck up at just the second example sentence:

> She dashed off to her room.

The meaning of 'off' this sentence is an example of is, "away from the place in question; to or at a distance".

If I omit 'off' from the sentence, it seems okay to me:

> She dashed to her room.  [She ran in hurry to her room.]

What does 'off' do here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*"She dashed off to her room"* means that she went away from the place where she was and which isn't mentioned in the sentence, and dashed to her room. So with **off** there's the added meaning of going away from a particular place which isn't included in *"She dashed to her room".*

EDIT upon comment: There's the phrasal verb [dash off](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/dash_2) which means *write or draw something very quickly*. Its use is totally different from the use of the preposition **off** described above.

Comment: Now I dashed off a comment to you, apparently from nowhere. Haven't I?

Comment: Ah, @Kris, idiomatic use of *dash off* is different to literal use, as I'm sure you know.